# How to call and reuse function from file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In the below script would I like to read the content of `config.toml`, and have marked where I would like to do that. What confuses me is how to include the `toml.js` file which contains the toml reader function.

Throughout the script will I need to read 3 different toml files.

**Question**

How should I include the `toml.js` function and how to reuse the function to read 3 different files?

Disclaimer: I am sorry for this super noob question, but this is my first project, and with [6 different ways to write a function](https://dmitripavlutin.com/6-ways-to-declare-javascript-functions/), I find it very confusing.

**index.js**

```
'use strict'
var minimist = require('minimist')
const toml = require('./src/toml')

module.exports = () => {
var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
  string: 'input',
  string: 'project',
  boolean: ['validate'],
  boolean: ['help'],
  alias: { i: 'input', v: 'validate', h: 'help', p: 'project' },
  unknown: function () { console.log('Unkown argument') }
})

  if (argv.help || argv.h) {
    // help output goes here
  }

  // read config.toml

}
```

**src/toml.js**

```
module.exports = (filename) => {
  const TOML = require('@iarna/toml')
  const fs = require('fs');

  return TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have everything set up correctly. Inside index.js you should be able to use `toml('filename.toml')`. This function returns the contents of filename.toml as an object.

src/toml.js exports a function that parses a .toml file. When you use `const toml = require('./src/toml')` inside index.js, you are assigning `toml` to the exports of ./src/toml.js (which is the parsing function). This means that in index.js, `toml` represents the function in ./src/toml.js.

You can then use the `toml('filename.toml')` as many times as you want in index.js.

Here is your index.js code modified to read the config.toml file and store the object in `config`...

```
'use strict'
var minimist = require('minimist')
const toml = require('./src/toml')

module.exports = () => {
  var argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2), {
    string: 'input',
    string: 'project',
    boolean: ['validate'],
    boolean: ['help'],
    alias: { i: 'input', v: 'validate', h: 'help', p: 'project' },
    unknown: function () { console.log('Unkown argument') }
  })

  if (argv.help || argv.h) {
    // help output goes here
  }

  // read config.toml
  const config = toml('config.toml')

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to call `toml('path/to/config/that/you/want/to/read.toml')`

You have required a module **src/toml.js**. This module exports a function - doesn't really matter how this function is declared in this case. Whenever you import that module - you are given this function.

So:

```js
const iCanCallThisReferenceHoweverIWant = require('./src/toml');
iCanCallThisReferenceHoweverIWant('path/to/a/toml/file.toml');
```

I think you need to require your dependencies in the `toml.js` outside of the function definition - I assume it may yell at you about that, but I'm not super-duper-confident about it :)

Proposition + some refactoring:

**src/toml.js**

```js
const TOML = require('@iarna/toml')
const fs = require('fs');

const readTOML = (filename) => TOML.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8'));
module.exports = readTOML;
```